# CSS Horizontal Navigation Bar Alignment Problem in Firefox

Tags: firefox, html, css, navigationbar

My navigation bar is off in Firefox and Opera. There is noticeably more padding below the text than above. I've changed my code so many different times trying to fix this, so I apologize if there are errors in my current code. It looks fine in Safari and Chrome. Can anyone help find my error(s)?

CSS:

```
ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
margin-bottom: 50px;
}

li {
display: inline;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

a.one:link,a.one:visited {
font-size: 18px;
line-height: 18px;
font-weight: bold;
background-color: red;
color: white;
font-family: Helvetica,Arial,san-serif;
text-align: center;
padding: 5px 7px;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-shadow: 0.05em 0.05em 0.1em #333;
letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
    <li><a class=one href=index.html>home</a></li>
    <li><a class=one href=bio.html>bio</a></li>
    <li><a class=one href=news.html>news</a></li>
    <li><a class=one href=disc.html>discography</a></li>
    <li><a class=one href=contact.html>contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> There is noticeably more padding below the text than above.

Here is the issue:

- Since `margin:0;` and `margin-bottom: 50px` is set, the above/below ratio is 0px/50px

> It looks fine in Safari and Chrome

Compare the default stylesheets:

- [WebCore(Safari): html.css](http://svn.webkit.org/repository/webkit/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/html.css)
- [Mozilla(Firefox): html.css](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/layout/style/html.css)
- [Blink(Chromium/Opera): html.css](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/blink/trunk/Source/core/css/html.css)
- [Internet Explorer User Agent Style Sheets](http://www.iecss.com/)

And lookup the vendor extensions:

- [Mozilla CSS Extensions: -moz-padding-start](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-padding-start)